# including phtml file in phtml in magento

Tags: magento, php

Hi I have added the inchoo featured products but want them to show in the header so show on everypage, i tried moving the code, i tried:

```
 echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template', 'block-name')->setData('template', 'inchoo/block_featured_products.phtml')->toHtml()
```

Im kind of new to **magento** so i don't know

thanks
Graham

Answer (score 0):

Create a CMS static block and give a identifier name to that, lets say "featured_product".
Open page.xml file from app/design/frontend/default/YOURTEMPLATE/layout/page.xml
Find the section html_header, now add the following code

```
<block type="cms/block" name="header_block"><action method="setBlockId"><block_id>featured_product</block_id></action></block>
```

Next open the app/design/frontend/default/YOURTEMPLATE/template/page/html/header.phtml file.
Find the area to design and add the following code in there :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('featured_product') ?>
```

Clean cache and test your page.

Comment: sorry I forgot to change something. Could you please change the following line (header_block should be featured_product):

<block type="cms/block" name="featured_product"><action method="setBlockId"><block_id>featured_product</block_id></action></block>

**page.xml shoul be :**

<block type=”page/html_header” name=”header” as=”header”>
<block type="cms/block" name="featured_product"><action method="setBlockId"><block_id>featured_product</block_id></action></block>
<block type=”core/text_list” name=”top.menu” as=”topMenu”/>